# Implementing an iterator over combinations of many vectors

Tags: c++, vector, boost, iterator

I am working on a problem that requires iterating over all combinations of elements of `K` vectors taken one at a time. So for example for `K=2` vectors `v1 = [0 1]` and `v2 = [3 4]`, I would iterate over `(0,3), (0,4), (1,3), (1,4)`.

Since `K` is determined at run-time, I cannot use explicit for loops. My current approach is based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1703575/5471520) that implements an "odometer" incrementing an index for each vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v1( {1, 2, 3} );
    std::vector<int> v2( {-2, 5} );
    std::vector<int> v3( {0, 1, 2} );
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > vv( {v1, v2 ,v3} );

    // Iterate combinations of elems in v1, v2, v3, one at a time
    std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator> vit;
    for (auto& v : vv)
        vit.push_back(v.begin());
    int K = vv.size();
    while (vit[0] != vv[0].end()) 
    {
        std::cout << "Processing combination: ["; 
        for (auto& i : vit)
            std::cout << *i << " ";
        std::cout << "]\n";

        // increment "odometer" by 1
        ++vit[K-1];
        for (int i = K-1; (i > 0) && (vit[i] == vv[i].end()); --i) 
        {
        vit[i] = vv[i].begin();
        ++vit[i-1];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Processing combination: [1 -2 0 ]
Processing combination: [1 -2 1 ]
Processing combination: [1 -2 2 ]
Processing combination: [1 5 0 ]
Processing combination: [1 5 1 ]
Processing combination: [1 5 2 ]
Processing combination: [2 -2 0 ]
Processing combination: [2 -2 1 ]
Processing combination: [2 -2 2 ]
Processing combination: [2 5 0 ]
Processing combination: [2 5 1 ]
Processing combination: [2 5 2 ]
Processing combination: [3 -2 0 ]
Processing combination: [3 -2 1 ]
Processing combination: [3 -2 2 ]
Processing combination: [3 5 0 ]
Processing combination: [3 5 1 ]
Processing combination: [3 5 2 ]
```

However, this is somewhat messy and requires a lot of boilerplate code that I'd rather move elsewhere for clarity. Ideally I would like to have a custom iterator class, say `my_combination_iterator`, that would allow me to do things much cleaner, e.g.:

```
for (my_combination_iterator it = vv.begin(); it != vv.end(); ++it)
    // process combination
```

So far, I have looked at [Boost `iterator_facade`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html#tutorial-example). But my case seems more complicated than the one in the tutorial since I would need an iterator over a vector of `Value`s as opposed to a single value type to define the required operators for the custom iterator.
How could such an iterator be implemented?

Comment: I finally had some spare-time to try implementing a proper bi-directional combinations iterator. You can find it [here](https://github.com/artem-ogre/combinations_cpp). I did not use boost, so the code is more verbose than it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you like to use custom iterators?
One could instead implement a very simple class that will iterate through all combinations:

```
class Combinator
{
public:
    Combinator(std::vector<std::vector<int> >& vectors)
        : m_vectors(vectors)
    {
        m_combination.reserve(m_vectors.size());
        for(auto& v : m_vectors)
            m_combination.push_back(v.begin());
    }

    bool next()
    {
        // iterate through vectors in reverse order
        for(long long i = m_vectors.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            std::vector<int>& v = m_vectors[i];
            std::vector<int>::iterator& it = m_combination[i];

            if(++it != v.end())
                return true;
            it = v.begin();
        }
        return false;
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator> combination() const
    {
        return m_combination;
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int> >& m_vectors; // reference to data
    std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator> m_combination;
};
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/81BZQKyBl5Vd2yT5)</kbd>

**UPDATE:**
If you would still like to use iterators, I suggest iterating over combinations. One can put all the combinations from `Combinator` into a container and then work with container's own iterators. In my opinion it's a cleaner solution. The only drawback is the extra-memory needed to store all combinations explicitly.

Comment: This is practically an iterator. Add the missing operators, add a default constructor, inherit from [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) and you're there.

Comment: This is a reasonable suggestion. I am interested in using a custom iterator as it would allow to directly apply STL algorithms that work on iterator ranges. I think it would also be still clearer in signaling the intent of how to use the code.

Comment: @mikkola you can put all the combinations from `Combinator` into a container and then work with container's iterators. IMO it's a cleaner solution. The only drawback is the memory overhead needed to store all combinations explicitly.

Comment: @AMA in the end I went with a slight variation of this, so I'm accepting this as an answer. Thanks for your time!