# How to generate tupled combinations of arbitrary number of vectors

Tags: c++, combinatorics, cartesian-product

This question was [kind of asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700079/howto-create-combinations-of-several-vectors-without-hardcoding-loops-in-c), but I'm not sure a satisfactory response was really offered. For me, I'm not interested in landing in a `std::vector` of `std::string`, per se, but rather a `std::tuple`.

For instance, if I've got `std::vector<A>`, `std::vector<B>`, and `std::vector<C>`, then I expect perhaps `std::vector<std::tuple<A, B, C>>`. Or, even `std::set<std::tuple<A, B, C>>`, if that was more appropriate.

Now, I could encode nested `for` loops, however, I'd like to do this via functions, template functions if possible, then I suppose variadic would be necessary to accomplish the task.

There are no guarantees that `A`, `B`, or `C` have anything to do with each other, much less conversion to `std::string`, as were proposed in a couple of the responses.

I want to say there could be a variadic solution to that, but I'm not exactly sure how to compose the `std::vector<T>` or `std::vector<T>::value_type` definitions.

Comment: Is there a guarantee that the sizes of `std::vector<A>`, `std::vector<B>`, and `std::vector<C>` are the same? Or you are fine with getting some `tuple`s that are missing some of their parts?

Comment: What is your question exactly? I understand the question you linked to, but it sounds like you are asking something different

Comment: @Fureeish: I think the OP wants a Cartesian product, not combinations, so matched input lengths aren't important.

Comment: If Cartesian product is the case then you are completely right about irrelevance of their length

Comment: Any of the vectors are not guaranteed to be the same size whatsoever. For instance, if I could index into them, I might approach it as an Odometer type of problem, tracking the index for each vector at each stage.

Comment: To be clear, I'm looking for combinations. I just can't guarantee they map to strings, per se. So I literally want a ``vector`` of ``tuple<A, B, C>``.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compute the Cartesian product of heterogeneous vectors, you may do something like:

```
template <std::size_t N>
bool increase(const std::array<std::size_t, N>& sizes, std::array<std::size_t, N>& it)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        const std::size_t index = N - 1 - i;
        ++it[index];
        if (it[index] >= sizes[index]) {
            it[index] = 0;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename F, std::size_t ... Is, std::size_t N, typename Tuple>
void apply_impl(F&& f,
                std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                const std::array<std::size_t, N>& it,
                const Tuple& tuple)
{
    f(std::get<Is>(tuple)[it[Is]]...);
}

template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
void iterate(F&& f, const std::vector<Ts>&... vs)
{
    constexpr std::size_t N = sizeof...(Ts);
    std::array<std::size_t, N> sizes{{vs.size()...}};
    std::array<std::size_t, N> it{{(vs.size(), 0u)...}};

    do {
        apply_impl(f, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>(), it, std::tie(vs...));
    } while (increase(sizes, it));
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/8vMOKt)

Comment: The index vectors could become index arrays, as size is fixed and known at compile time.

Comment: Interesting, so I wasn't too clear on the variadic expansion from types into vectors.

Comment: @Yakk: array used instead of vector.

Comment: If you change vs from `const std::vector<Ts>&... vs` to `Ts&&...vs` you can use both rvalue vectors as well as other STL compatible  containers such as std::array and QVector (tested with gcc 4.8.5). Although I did need a `static_cast<std::size_t>(vs.size())` for the first vs.size when I used a QVector.