# How to create combinations of several vectors OF DIFFERING TYPES without hardcoding loops in C++

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

The following question asks about finding "all combinations" of `n` vectors of THE SAME TYPE, e.g. `std::string`: [Howto create combinations of several vectors without hardcoding loops in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700079/howto-create-combinations-of-several-vectors-without-hardcoding-loops-in-c)

(This means, concatenating all possible combinations to strings and printing these.)

So, for

```
std::vector<std::string> v1{ "T", "C", "A" };
std::vector<std::string> v2{ "C", "G", "A" };
std::vector<std::string> v3{ "C", "G", "T" };
```

we'd get:

```
TCC
TCG
TCT
TGC
TGG
TGT
TAC
TAG
TAT
CCC
CCG
CCT
CGC
CGG
CGT
CAC
CAG
CAT
ACC
ACG
ACT
AGC
AGG
AGT
AAC
AAG
AAT
```

One answer using recursion is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1700227/7302562

Is the same possible with vectors holding different types, by using variadic templates?

So, for example:

```
std::vector<std::string> v1{ "T", "C", "A" };
std::vector<int> v2{ 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<float> v3{ 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 };
```

should gain a string like this (the exact formatting is not so important; I'm just interested in the structure of the function):

```
T-1-1.1
T-1-2.2
...
T-2-1.1
T-2-2.2
...
A-3-3.3
```

(And if so, can we pass a `std::function` or something similar along with the vectors to specify what to do, instead of doing the hard-coded concatenation?)

(I'm just beginning to wrap my head around variadic templates, so my first attempt is not really showable... And I hope the question is not in itself stupid...)

Comment: *vectors of different types* - what does that mean? `std::vector` holding elements of different types or several `std::vector<T>` with distinct `T`?

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to do. What are your proposed inputs and output?

Comment: Sorry, you're right! I have added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **std::variant**. It's a template that lets you have two or more types in a variable. Example:

```
std::variant<std::string, int> myVariant = 3;
```

The only problem that has this implementation is that you will need to know the **type** of the variable if you want to get its value. Example:

```
if(holds_alternative<int>(myVariant){
   std::get<int> myVariant // 3
}
```

But, if you want to use just primitive types or strings, it will be easier:

```
std::vector<std::variant<std::string, int>> v1{ "T", 4, "A", 83 };
```

If you want to use arbitrary types, you can also use **std::any**. It allows every type.

```
std::vector<std::any> v1{"T", 4, 2.5, '\n'} // ... and the types you want
```

Comment: Instead of `holds_alternative`, it might be better to have a visitor

Comment: That's a nice solution with the variant! (I gave an upvote.) But the downside is that I'd need to know the allowed types beforehand. The ideal function I'm thinking of should just loop through all combinations of an aribtrary number of arbitrary-sized vectors, each holding an arbitrary type - and do "something".

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. That would work! I would have liked the vectors to each have a specific type T, though. Anyway, your answer comes reasonably close...